# Need help with code golf

Tags: discussion, code-golf

What in the world is code golf and how is it important to me? I have already looked in the tour.

Comment: In order to find more about a topic, if it's a tag you can go to [the tag page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and click [learn more](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info).

Answer (score 5):

Code Golf is a mostly-recreational semi-competitive exercise in writing code, where the objective is to accomplish the aim using the least amount of code in the programming language chosen. (Compare with the familiar game of golf, where the objective is to get the ball into the hole with the least number of strokes.)

Only you can decide how – or whether – it is important to you.

With some languages, “golfing” encourages familiarity with “idiomatic” constructions. It also encourages thinking “out of the box” when attempting to solve the given problem.